# Saving user latest searches in local storage

Tags: angular

I have a website with some kind of search feature. I wish to log the user latest searches. My question:

Using the browser local storage can be good idea? If it will be around 50 searches in the local storage in JSON format, it may work slow?

Does saving this data in database can work better?

My app is built using Angular 2 and php backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local storage can handle 50 entries easily.

If saving it server-side is better, depends on what you want:

If you save it in local storage, you can provide recent searches without needing a login.
However, the data will be machine-bound, so even if people are logged in, they will see different recent searches on different devices, e.g. their phone and desktop. That can be annoying. Also, wiping the browser-storage will obviously wipe the data.

For the best UX you should combine the two, and save recent searches in local storage for users without login and save them server-side for users logged into an account.

Comment: Thanks. I get that